# C Program Error: Conflicting types for getname

Tags: c

I am stuck in this code as it keeps producing error. I copied it from my school notes so it should not be wrong. But it is not be able to execute.

Here is my code:

[image: Here is my code.]

Here is the error message:
[image: Here is the error message.]

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post links to screenshots of your code, instead include the code in the body of your question.

Comment: getname() is also an API function, give it a different name.

Comment: The origin of the problem is the warning "Implicit declaration...". Consider the warnings "Implicit declaration..." always as errors. Put your `getname` function _before_ `main`.

Answer (score 1):

While compiling `main()`, the compiler is not *seeing* your `getname()` function, that is defined later. Compiler *assumes*, that function has no nay arguments and has return type `int`. However, when compiler finally reaches `getname()` function, it realizes that actual return value type of `getname()` is different (in your case `struct nameTag`).

The solution can be done with 2 options:

A). Put `getname()` function body above `main()` (where it is referenced first time). In that case, when compiler reaches `main()` it will already *know* the `getname()` function correct arguments and return type.

```
struct nameTag { char fname[20]; char Iname[20]; };

struct nameTag getname() // Defined before first use
{
     // Body of getname() function
}

main()
{
     // body of your main() function
}
```

B). *Declare* your `getname()` function *before*  first reference to it in `main()`, to tell compiler that it exists somewhere in a way:

```
struct nameTag { char fname[20]; char Iname[20]; };
struct nameTag getname(); // Function declaration, pay attention to ';' at end and no body
main()
{
     // body of your main() function
}

struct nameTag getname()
{
     // Body of getname() function
}
```

Postnote:
As for me, option A is preferred for local module functions, but in some cases option B if required (for example, in case of mutual reference between two or more functions). Also option B is used in *header* files (.h files), as they do not contain function bodies at all, only declarations.